# Angular 4 - Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-reactive-forms

I am getting the below error. `addControl` has the following signature. Not sure what i am doing wrong.

```
(method) FormGroup.addControl(name: string, control: AbstractControl): void
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FormBuilder.control` method has the following signature

```
control(formState: Object, validator?: ValidatorFn | ValidatorFn[] | null, asyncValidator?: AsyncValidatorFn | AsyncValidatorFn[] | null): FormControl;
```

So it requires the initial value. You have to pass `formState` like

```
this.fb.control('')
```

or

```
this.fb.control(null)
```

Here is how your code should look

```
createGroup() {
  const group = this.fb.group({});
  this.config.forEach(control => group.addControl(control.name, this.fb.control('')));
  return group;
}
```